# Mostrar data anterior de un select-Laravel

Tags: laravel

Adjunto un fragmento de la edit blade de la clase Appointment . El código de la zona de interés en cuestión es el siguiente :

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6 ">
  <label for="exampleInputState1">Estado</label>
  <select id="exampleInputState1" class="form-control" name="state">
  <option value="normal" @if(old('state') == 'normal')selected @endif>normal</option>
    <option value="cancelada" @if(old('state') == 'cancelada')selected @endif>cancelada</option>
    <option value="aplazada" @if(old('state') == 'aplazada')selected @endif>aplazada</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**Edit blade de Appointment**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@include('layouts.menu')
@section('content')

<div class="container" style="padding:70px 0">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
<div class="col-md-8">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header">Editar cita</div>
<div class="card-body">



<form action="updateAppointment" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="{{ $appointment->id }}"/>

 <div class="form-group col-md-10" >
 <label for="exampledateAndHour1">Fecha y hora</label>
 <input value="{{ old('dateAndHour',$appointment->dateAndHour) }}" 
 name="dateAndHour" type="datetime-local" class="form-control" 
  id="exampledateAndHour1"  >

    </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-6 ">
  <label for="exampleInputState1">Estado</label>
  <select id="exampleInputState1" class="form-control" name="state">
  <option value="normal" @if(old('state') == 'normal')selected @endif>normal</option>
    <option value="cancelada" @if(old('state') == 'cancelada')selected @endif>cancelada</option>
    <option value="aplazada" @if(old('state') == 'aplazada')selected @endif>aplazada</option>
  </select>
</div>



<div class="form-group col-md-10">
<label for="exampleInputHeader1">Título</label>
<input value="{{ old('header',$appointment->header) }}" 
type="text"name="header" class="form-control" id="exampleInputHeader1" >
</div>


  <div class="form-group col-md-10">
  <label for="exampleInputDescription1">Descripción</label>
  <input value="{{ old('description',$appointment->description) }}" 
  type="text" name="description" class="form-control" 
  id="exampleInputDescription1" >
 </div>

 <div class="form-group col-md-6">
<label for="patient">ID Paciente</label>
<select name="patient_id" id="exampleInputIDPatient1" class="form-control" required autofocus>
@foreach($patients as $patient)
<option value="{{ $patient->id }}">{{ $patient->id }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>

</div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label for="doctor">ID Doctor</label>
  <select name="doctor_id" id="exampleInputIDDoctor1" class="form-control" required autofocus>
   @foreach($doctors as $doctor)
  <option value="{{ $doctor->id}}">{{ $doctor->id}}</option>
  @endforeach
  </select>
   </div>



    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
      </form>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   @endsection
```

No hay ningún problema a la hora de mostrar los antiguos valores de description y header. Sin embargo, en state no se muestra el valor antiguo seleccionado. Por ejemplo, al editar una cita cuyo state era inicialmente igual a "cancelada", al abrir el formulario de edición se tiene:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé como solucionar este problema, y de hecho se me produce con otras variables de Appointment como dateAndHour. ¿Quizás la forma de obtener los datos anteriores del select no es la más adecuada?

**Edición: captura de lo que aparece en código fuente**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muestro también dateAndHour para que se vea que en ese caso sí se recibe el valor anterior.

Adjunto código de los métodos implicados del controlador de Appointment:

**a)Edit-AppointmentController:**

```
public function edit(Request $request)
{
    //
    $appointment = Appointment::findOrFail($request->id);
    $doctors = Doctor::all();
    $patients = Patient::all();
    return view ('appointments/edit')->with('appointment',$appointment)->with('doctors',$doctors)->with('patients',$patients);
}
```

**b)Update-AppointmentController**

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    //
    $appointment = Appointment::findOrFail($request->id);
    $this->validate($request,[
      'doctor_id' => 'required',
      'patient_id' => 'required',
      'dateAndHour' => 'required',
      'state' => 'required',
      'header' => 'required',
      'description' => 'required|max:500'
    ]);
    $input = $request->all();
    $appointment->fill($input)->save();
    return Redirect::to('appointments');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al estar todo en una linea deberias utilizar las llaves para mostrar el string, es decir `{{'selected'}}`, ejemplo

```
<select id="exampleInputState1" class="form-control" name="state">
  <option value="normal" @if(old('state') == 'normal') {{'selected'}} @endif>normal</option>
  <option value="cancelada" @if(old('state') == 'cancelada') {{'selected'}} @endif>cancelada</option>
  <option value="aplazada" @if(old('state') == 'aplazada') {{'selected'}} @endif>aplazada</option>
</select>
```

Otra opción mas elegante puede ser prescindiendo de los if de blade y utilizar el operador ternario de php, ejemplo:

```
<select id="exampleInputState1" class="form-control" name="state">
  <option value="normal" {{ old('state') == 'normal' ? 'selected' : '' }}>normal</option>
  <option value="cancelada" {{ old('state') == 'cancelada' ? 'selected' : '' }}>cancelada</option>
  <option value="aplazada" {{ old('state') == 'aplazada' ? 'selected' : '' }}>aplazada</option>
</select>
```

Una opción que facilita el trabajo con formularios en blade es el paquete [laravelcollective/html](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html)

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, Laravel Collective facilita bastante la tarea, aunque para este trabajo en concreto se ha indicado que mejor lo haga sin utilizarlo. He probado las dos soluciones y sigue mostrándose el estado "normal" por defecto. Añado en la pregunta una captura de lo que aparece en el código fuente.

Comment: @Montu Puedes adjuntar el metodo del controlador implicado? Otra opcion podria se usando `Request::input('state')` en lugar de `old('state')`. Trata de imprimir `old('state')` en algun lugar para saber que valor contiene.

Comment: Creo que ya he conseguido solucionarlo. Añado respuesta. Muchas gracias por su ayuda, me ha sido de gran utilidad.

Answer (score 0):

La solución aportada por Xerif es correcta, simplemente había que añadir esto:

```
<option value="cancelada" {{ old('state',$appointment->state) == 'cancelada' ? 
'selected' : '' }}>cancelada</option>
```

Es decir, añadir `$appointment->state`.